# Tableview header position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a tableView grouped style and after set headers for each group, its text is superposed to first cell. How to position group down in order to see header's text on top and previous to cell group? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a plain (not grouped) style?

Comment: Could you please post your code here?

Comment: @Ruth You should post code and screenshots.

Comment: tableView:viewForHeaderInSection solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've implemented the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method to create header views, try to also implement the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method. Both are part of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol